# WordPress Website & AWS CloudFront Integration: Not accepting credentials from one account, but accepting from another

Tags: wordpress, amazon-aws, plugin, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to implement CloudFront CDN on my WordPress website. I am using "AWS for WordPress" plugin as recommended in the official AWS documentation here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accelerating-wordpress-with-cloudfront-using-the-aws-for-wordpress-plugin/

The strange thing is, when I enter the credentials (access id and secret key) of my *test* AWS account, it accepts the key and moves forward. However, when I enter the creds of my *production* AWS account, it gives me an error like so.

[image]

I made sure that I assigned the exact same permissions in AWS IAM to both the users, the one from my test account, and the other from my production account. For my test account it moves forward to the next screen for CloudFront like so.

[image]

Needless to add, I am using the exact same website for both the account credentials. Just cannot figure out where I may be going wrong.

To narrow down the problem even further, I also tried entering an incorrect secret key in the plugin, in which case it doesn't even show the error screen. This makes it pretty obvious that it is in fact accepting accepting my credentials, but is receiving an error from the AWS end.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: It says it emailed the admin more info about the error.  Did you check your email?